# Typo3: The requested page didn't have a proper connection to the tree-root

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.1.x, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-4.5

I want to update a TYPO3 Project from 4.1 to 6.2.9. In order to do that I need to upgrade it to find the most compatible extensions. So I've updated the TYPO3 to 4.5. Now the back end loaded and it shows some arguments that are printed. Also in front end it shows this error.

```
The requested page didn't have a proper connection to the tree-root!<br /><br />(Broken rootline (failed on page with uid 7))
```

Comment: There are countless possibilities why this can happen. I suggest you manually uninstall all third-party extensions (removing them vom extList and extList_FE in localconf.php), clear the caches and try again. "Some arguments are printed" is not very helpful, please add details.

Comment: Dear lorenz, After going to Install tool. In DB Analyser there are so many tables are not properly indexed. After fixing that this issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue.

After going to Install tool. In DB Analyser there are so many tables are not properly indexed. After fixing that this issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Truncate `realURL`-tables and clear Cache via InstallTool.
This works for me.